# Evenly Space 28 divs in a 100% wide container

Tags: css, fluid

I know it is possible to evenly space divs with the same width inside of a fixed width container, but what about fluid width container?

I plan to have 28 divs with no space between them side by side. Twenty six will have a single letter of the alphabet, one will have the text 'all' and the last will have a pound sign in it.

Is this possible? Probably with CSS3 calc? If so how can I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just float the divs, and set their width to 1/28th of the width of the parent using the % unit:

http://jsfiddle.net/GgrKU/

```
#parent {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden
}
#parent > div {
    width: 3.5714%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```